# What are the best beginner tutorials for Selenium IDE 

Tags: selenium, learning

I have gone through the possible duplicate question,it was related to **selenium webdriver** .

I am new to Selenium IDE tool. Could you please suggest me some best PDFs and sites with Selenium tutorials for beginners.

As the two questions mentioned here were related to **webdriver** and the answer overviews the selenium tool,

can anyone say the valid sources for learning selenium ide

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selenium Simplified
http://compendiumdev.co.uk/selenium/

Comment: Sorry I had not seen your answer

Comment: And a great advert by the author himself:http://www.eviltester.com/index.php/2011/06/02/how-can-i-learn-to-automate-my-testing-using-selenium/

Answer (score 1):

I think you already seen [official selenium documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/) but it good place to start. Since you do not specified  which  Selenium tool you what to learn. For example *Selenium IDE* and *Selenium with Web Driver* is different tools and need different knowledge to use. While reading official documentation can help you to decide from which one begin learn.

Answer (score 1):

http://qtpselenium.com/samplevideos/selenium/seleniumvideos.php

It's a pay site, but it has been great for me.  All video tutorials with optional online classes, great forums, access to interview q&a, covers java basics also.  Also, has a lot of try before you buy videos you can check out to decide if you like it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this book really help full
http://compendiumdev.co.uk/selenium/

It takes you step by step from selenium IDE , selenium 1 and selenium 2 (webdriver)