# how to start work with selenium web driver any reference site for selenium web driver?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find information on getting started with Selenium 2](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/295/where-can-i-find-information-on-getting-started-with-selenium-2)

I want to learn selenium web driver from the scratch. any one suggest me the reference site for selenium web driver.

Thanks & regards!
Vinod Guneja

Comment: Have you tried looking yourself ? Did you try the official site, have you looked for books ?

Comment: Official getting started guide with link to next steps: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: @phil Yes, i have tried the official site but the material provided at the official site is tough to understand.can you give me a other alternative.

Comment: @Vinod Did you read this thread ? http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2334/what-are-the-best-beginner-tutorials-for-selenium

Answer (score 2):

I have found the official site a bit difficult for just starting out with Selenium, as well. Here are some resources, in addition to those listed at the link mentioned above:

Some free online tutorials are available here: http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/selenium_training.htm

Kavin School offers classes, both the kind you can attend and the kind you can download and run at your own pace. Just search for "Kavin School".

When you get up to your elbows in Selenium, and you are getting frustrated with figuring out xpaths, my friend wrote a helpful script: http://teddyb.org/rlp/tiki-index.php?page=XPath+Tester+For+Selenium

Also: while the official site may be hard to navigate, I have found their chat room to be very friendly to beginners, as long as you try to search the chat archive for an answer to your question first.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just try ths Site.It helps lot for me and i hope it'll helps you.

- [mearra.com](http://mearra.com/blogs/jani-palsamaki/creating-and-running-simple-selenium-webdriver-test#comment-847)
- [maven.apache.org](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-ide-eclipse.html)
- [ibm.com](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-selenium2/)

Answer (score 0):

There's a very basic introduction below that should get you started (using C#).

[Interacting with web pages using Selenium WebDriver for C#](http://www.jimmycollins.org/blog/?p=583)